# How to get git-completion.bash to work on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, git

I have followed http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/27983389/git-utilities-you-cant-live-without to 
add `git-completion.bash` to my `/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion`

and I put `PS1='\h:\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \u\$ '` in my .bashrc_profile

But now I am getting this `-bash: __git_ps1: command not found` everything I do a `cd`.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: See also: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I installed git using [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) on my new Snow Leopard installation.  After MacPorts is installed from the .dmg image, these would be the commands in Terminal.app:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install git-core +bash_completion
```

If you also want support for pulling from SVN repositories and docs, use this instead of the second line:

```
sudo port install git-core +bash_completion +doc +svn
```

Then add the following to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile:

```
# MacPorts Bash shell command completion
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

or for MacPorts since version 2.1.2 on Mountain Lion:

```
# MacPorts Bash shell command completion
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ]; then
  . /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
fi
```

or for MacPorts with newer versions of git:

```
if [ -f /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh ]; then
    . /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
fi
```

Note: bash 4.1 or higher is required by bash_completion.sh. If completion doesn't work try `echo $BASH_VERSION` to see if that's the issue. If so, enter MacPorts bash by typing `bash` and try git completion again.

Comment: I just copy pasted, and I still get the error the OP has. =\. How do you tell what's been included? I don't thenk bash_completion is sourced

Comment: note with newer versions of git/macport/bash-completion the prompt is in a different file.  See: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/36334 

`if [ -f /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh ]; then
      . /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
fi`

Comment: Because `/opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` needs `$BASH_VERSION` 4.1 or better, I had to do the following on a Mac OS X 10.8.3 with MacPorts 2.1.3: Switch the Mac OS X login shell from its default `/bin/bash` (3.2.48(1)-release) to MacPorts `/opt/local/bin/bash` (4.2.42(2)-release) like its described here: stackoverflow.com/a/791244/287984. Basically ``if [ `grep /opt/local/bin/bash /etc/shells` ]; then echo /opt/local/bin/bash | chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash; else echo /opt/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells; chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash; fi``

Comment: Worked great for me. Had to replace `/bin/bash` in Terminal.app with `/opt/local/bin/bash` from macports + all the `.bash_profile` changes suggested here.

Comment: To move to bash 4.1 or later you can follow the instructions here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70132/set-default-shell-to-macports-bash-in-mac-os-x-10-6-8

Comment: OSX latest path is `/opt/local/share/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh` as per answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870928/mac-bash-git-ps1-command-not-found)

Answer (score 59):

If you installed git using homebrew than you might adjust the MacPorts advice a little and add this to your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
. `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi
```

The best way to check if you have git correctly installed using homebrew ist to execute

```
brew info git
```

and check the output for the install directory of the git bash completion

Latest version of Git (1.7.12) also requires the following to enable the prompt.

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh
fi
```

Comment: For more on ``__git_ps1``, see http://superuser.com/a/477749/90231 answer in this stack.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even knew this came along with git when installed with homebrew. They should automatically append this to `~/.bash_profile`, I wonder who wouldn't want this.

Answer (score 26):

All you need to do is place the `git-completion.bash` file in your user home `bin` directory and place the following in you `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
source ~/bin/git-completion.bash
PS1='[\u@\h \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

What this does is make sure that your local bin is in the PATH and the `source` command gets things going. Then of course the PS1 change puts the currently checked out branch in the prompt.

So, no MacPort install to then install a the "completion" version of GIT (especially irritating if you already have it installed).

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: For those wondering how to combine that PS1 thing with colors in your prompt see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816790/append-gits-branch-name-to-command-prompt

Comment: More precisely, git-completion.bash just needs to be somewhere in your `$PATH`. I decided to put mine in `/usr/local/bin/` so that I didn't have to modify my existing `$PATH`.

Answer (score 13):

While the current answer is correct for older MacPorts there is a new issue with the most current MacPorts resulting in the same error.

The current *bash-completion* package (2.0 r1) requires at least a bash 4.1 to function properly. As a usual OS X Terminal uses `/bin/bash` it only gets a 3.x. You have to change you terminal settings to use `/opt/local/bin/bash -l` as described in the MacPorts documentation here: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion

Comment: This is the most correct answer as I only started having the problem after updating macports. The only downside to using the macports bash from terminal is that it now warns me about terminating running processes when I try to close my terminal window - have you run into this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to source the command completion functions. Add to your .bashrc_profile before the PS1:

```
. /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion
```

Comment: git-completion.bash can be found here: https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 5):

Annoyingly this has been broken yet again. This time its the git folks with version 1.7.12-1. To allow people to have just the prompt functionality without the completion functionality (which can slows things down), they refactored the prompt functionality out of bash_completion/git and into its own file git-prompt.sh.

So adding bash_completion as described by @Lara will only get you completion (hitting tab completes tag/branch names).

To get the `__git_ps1` so you can use it in your PS1 prompt you also need to add the following to your ~/.profile.

`. /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`

Some background is here - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1163632#p1163632

Comment: The file in question: https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Answer (score 4):

Or with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install bash-completion git-extras
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should be `brew install bash-completion git-extras` though (dash instead of underscore).

Answer (score 4):

At least with Xcode 6, you already have `git-completion.bash`. It's inside the Xcode app bundle.

Just add this to your .bashrc:

```
source `xcode-select -p`/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
```

Comment: This was the only answer that actually worked for me. Other answers were producing strange errors when you type an incomplete command like `git br<TAB>`

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435117/ps1-env-variable-does-not-work-on-mac#comment14878214_10435238):

The [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) comes with `git-completion.bash` and installs it to `/usr/local/git/contrib/completion/`. Just source that file from your `.bash_profile` to get `__git_ps1`.

Answer (score 2):

For Mountain Lion and Mac-Ports I needed to use the following lines in my .bash_profile to get both __git_ps1 and completions to run normally:

```
# Bash shell command completion
if [ -f /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
fi

if [ -f /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh ]; then
  . /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I use brew, so a master `bash_completion` script which runs all the ones in `bash_completion.d` seems not to be provided.  The solutions which propose just running a single script to add git completions aren't extensible, because different packages will add different completion scripts, and you probably want to run them all.  Therefore I added this (adapted from Arch Linux) to the end of `/etc/bashrc`:

```
# source compat completion directory definitions
BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR=/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
if [[ -d $BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR && -r $BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR && \
    -x $BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR ]]; then
    for i in $(LC_ALL=C command ls "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR"); do
        i=$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR/$i
        [[ -f $i && -r $i ]] && . "$i"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adam K. Johnson's post

You can also put the following...

```
# MacPorts Bash shell command completion
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

...in your /etc/profile, if you want.

That way all users on the system will benefit from any bash completion scripts installed in the directory "/opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/".

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above by grundprinzip from 2011 still works fine, I wanted to add a more recent answer now that there's now a Homebrew package [bash-completion](http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash-completion) ([formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/977602501f3815b61f35c37b24d0bf1b262ee0c3/Formula/bash-completion.rb), [repo](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)) that makes this even easier.  (This includes completion for git as well as other common tools.)

Today macOS ships with Bash 3, but you can `brew install bash` to get Bash 4.  If you're running Bash 4, then install the newer 2.x branch of bash-completion.

### Bash 4

1. Run:

   ```
   brew install bash-completion@2
   ```
2. Add to `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
     . /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   fi
   ```

---

### Bash 3

If you want to stick with stock bash 3.x on macOS then follow these directions instead.

1. Run:

   ```
   brew install bash-completion
   ```
2. Add to `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   echo "[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion" >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

Reference: http://davidalger.com/development/bash-completion-on-os-x-with-brew/

Answer (score -2):

I think you maybe forget sourcing the file in your login `.bashrc`, you can add something like:

```
. ./path/to/your/file.ext
```

Using `.` followed by a space runs the file in the current context.