# Adding git branch to bash prompt on snow leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, bash, git, bashrc

I am using this:

```
$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')
```

It works however it does not update when I change directories or checkout a new branch. I also have this alias:

```
alias reload='. ~/.bash_profile'
```

**Sample run:**

```
user@machine:~/dev/rails$cd git_folder/
user@machine:~/dev/rails/git_folder$reload
user@machine:~/dev/rails/git_folder(test)$git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
user@machine:~/dev/rails/git_folder(test)$reload
user@machine:~/dev/rails/git_folder(master)$
```

As you can see it is being set correctly but only if I reload bash_profile.  I have wasted way to much time on this. I am using bash on snow leopard.  Please help!

Edit: You can see my dotfiles on github and the file setting the PS1 [here](http://github.com/crayment/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/config)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay problem solved.

I was doing:

```
export PS1="$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')"
```

and I needed to do:

```
export PS1="\$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')"
```

You need to escapee the dollar sign otherwise it is just run once and substituted in.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `$PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried playing with PROMPT_COMMAND but not working with my current setup.  You can see the file that makes the setting here: http://github.com/crayment/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/config

Answer (score 0):

Note that the latest git moves __git_ps1 out of bash_completion so you need to source it separately. See https://superuser.com/a/477749/66255.