# git bash-completion on mac osx does not work following standard installation instructions

Tags: macos, bash, git

I read a bunch of instructions for installing bash-completion for git, and settled on the macport solution, which is, for example, mentioned here: [How to get git-completion.bash to work on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/31744/how-to-get-git-completion-bash-to-work-on-mac-os-x)

However, this does not work, and I must call `source /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git` or put it in my .bashrc to activate git bash completion. Am I missing something? It seems like sourcing of a specific completion package should be more automatic, and no one on the web that I've found has listed this in their instructions for getting git bash-completion to work on mac os.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MacPorts' `bash-completion` script is supposed to live at `/opt/local/etc/bash-completion` and take care of sourcing everything inside `/opt/local/etc/bash-completion.d/*`. However, it is not installed by default.  You need to...

```
sudo port install bash-completion
```

...and then you still need to `source /opt/local/etc/bash-completion` from one of your bash startup scripts.

Note that the latest version of that script requires `bash` >= 4, which is later than is included with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.x (which includes `bash` 3.2.48(1)). *Update: OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.0 still appears to ship with `bash` 3.2.48(1), so this step is still needed even on Mountain Lion.* So make sure you've installed a later `bash` with MacPorts, and make sure you've configured Terminal.app (or whatever terminal you're using) to run `/opt/local/bin/bash` instead of OS X's default `/bin/bash`.

See also (recommended reading! good tips!): https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion

Comment: Changing terminal to run /opt/local/bin/bash resolved it. Can you tell me why this step is needed?

Comment: @jonderry That step is needed because the guys who maintain the bash-completion scripts have chosen to use features that are only in bash 4.x, and thus require bash 4.x, but OS X Lion only includes the older bash 3.2.x. If you look at `/opt/local/etc/bash-completion`, it explicitly checks your bash version before proceeding.

Comment: Is that still the path? /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ?

Comment: @claytontstanley Yes, the path I listed appears to be a more convenient symlink to the path you listed.