# -bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, .bash-profile

I recently uninstalled Homebrew and Cellar (web dev applications), and this error now appears after every Terminal command (although I can't confirm that these are the culprits!):

> -bash: __git_ps1: command not found.

I reinstalled both applications yet the error message still happens! I'm attaching my Bash file just incase it's related - [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/NSj2n0Lz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to look in your `~/.bash_prompt` file, or whatever file is setting `PS1` (the shell prompt format) for you. Your `PS1` variable is referencing the Git prompt function, which I assume got uninstalled or something. You'll want to remove the `$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")` part from your `PS1` value.

Comment: I've checked my ~/.bash_prompt file (see attached in original) and I can't find anything referencing that. Is there a quicker way of, say for instance, searching for this **PS1** value?

Comment: I didn't see your `~/.bash_prompt` file in your paste. But you can run a command like `find ~ -type f | xargs fgrep PS1=` to find where `PS1` is getting set. If it's not in `~`, then try replacing that with `/etc`.

Comment: Note: this might be a noob nitpicking, but I found the problematic line in my .bash_profile file, not .bash_prompt.

Comment: @BobMcBobson Yes, `~/.bash_prompt` was specific to the OP's question/environment. Most people will probably have it in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want (or eventually *might* want) to use `git`, then the git status in the prompt is quite useful. If using the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/), source `git-completion.bash` (e.g. found in `/usr/local/git/contrib/completion/`) from your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` or `.bash_prompt` etc), in order to to define the function `__git_ps1`.

Alternatively, you may prefer to install `git` & the corresponding git bash completion via macports (`sudo port install git-core +bash_completion`) or via homebrew, following the respective install steps for each. (See also: [How to get git-completion.bash to work on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/31744/how-to-get-git-completion-bash-to-work-on-mac-os-x))

The main gotcha for bash completion is that it requires a newer version of bash (>= 4.1) than comes w/ OSX by default, so you will want to install/use the newer bash that comes with macports/homebrew/etc. (`echo $BASH_VERSION`).

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with hacking your PS1 prompt or installing git & git completion, you may simply define the function yourself to be a no-op (e.g., in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` etc):

```
__git_ps1() { : ; }
```